# "is not a .NET module." what does it mean?

Tags: reflector

I'm using the beta 7.2 reflector, and when i'm trying to reflect some exe file i see this message. what does it mean ?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

It means that the EXE is not a [.NET assembly.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly)  It is a standard Windows executable or COM executable.

For example, programs written in VB6 are not .NET assemblies; they contain none of the [metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w45z383(v=vs.71).aspx) you would expect a .NET assembly to contain.

Comment: when i view file details (property -> details)  in Language it's being written
"Language neutral" 
what does it mean ?

Comment: Reflector disassembles to the language you specify. Since it's not a .NET assembly, reflector cannot disassemble it at all, so any attempt to ascribe a language to the assembly is meaningless.

Comment: i've tried to spy it by spy++ and it's being recognized as WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d is it .Net ?

Comment: According to Microsoft, that information is "undocumented," and cannot be relied upon.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/f09e691f-977e-4bcb-8f4b-5c0ed30f7b4e

Answer (score 3):

If it really is a .NET assembly (as some of your later comments, based on info from Spy++, suggest), then it's possibly been obfuscated. Some obfuscators can modify the assembly metadata streams to make them appear to be invalid to both ildasm and Reflector, whereas the CLR can still load them because it does not do as much validation.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Reflector can only decompile .NET assemblies. My guess would be that the executable is not a .NET executable and hence Reflector cannot load it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's looking for a CLI header indicating that the .exe is in fact a .NET assembly, and it doesn't look like the one you have qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reflect a COM or native executable/dynamic link library and not a .NET assembly. Reflector cannot do that. There are other tools for examining COM resources, although they will not completely dissassemble like Reflector does on .NET assemblies.

Comment: i've tried to spy it by spy ++ and it has been recognized as "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d"

also i've "played" a little with the app and crashed it (this process was attached to the debugger) then i got standard .net exception but couldn't see the source code.

is there any way to reflect this exe or, it's a waste of time ?

Comment: Where did you get this? Looking at the information you have added, I wonder if this is just a heavily obfuscated assembly.

Comment: Obfuscation can cause all sorts of issues. At the lowest level (Dotfuscator with VS, for example), it is simple symbol rename. At higher levels, it can completely stop decompilation. I have even seen older builds of reflector crash on certain obfuscated assemblies.

Comment: doesnt obfuscation makes your code harder to read? obscure - unclear

Comment: @Cromix obfuscation does make code harder to read, but that is its purpose. You are trying to make code more difficult to read so it cannot easily be decompiled. Remember .NET code is essentially pseudocode until it is JIT compiled by the system (at least in a "normal" implementation)